# How to spilt a 4GB .sql file into smaller files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a 4GB sql data script of my database. I want to execute it but SQL Server Management Studio does allow me to do it because it's a very big file.

So I want to split this file into smaller files so that I can execute it. I have googled it but didn't get any good solutions. I have also used HJSplit to split the files but only first split file is in correct format but others are not in correct format due to which can not be execute in SQL query Interface.

Please help me guys how can I execute this `.sql` file with data with or without splitting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170572.aspx) tool to execute the file..

```
sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql
```

or

```
sqlcmd -S <server> -i C:\<your file here>.sql -o
```

Just replace with the location of your SQL box and with the name of your script. Don't forget if you're using a SQL instance the syntax is:
sqlcmd -S \instance.

Here is the list of all arguments you can pass sqlcmd:

```
Sqlcmd            [-U login id]          [-P password]
  [-S server]            [-H hostname]          [-E trusted connection]
  [-d use database name] [-l login timeout]     [-t query timeout] 
  [-h headers]           [-s colseparator]      [-w screen width]
  [-a packetsize]        [-e echo input]        [-I Enable Quoted Identifiers]
  [-c cmdend]            [-L[c] list servers[clean output]]
  [-q "cmdline query"]   [-Q "cmdline query" and exit] 
  [-m errorlevel]        [-V severitylevel]     [-W remove trailing spaces]
  [-u unicode output]    [-r[0|1] msgs to stderr]
  [-i inputfile]         [-o outputfile]        [-z new password]
  [-f  | i:[,o:]] [-Z new password and exit] 
  [-k[1|2] remove[replace] control characters]
  [-y variable length type display width]
  [-Y fixed length type display width]
  [-p[1] print statistics[colon format]]
  [-R use client regional setting]
  [-b On error batch abort]
  [-v var = "value"...]  [-A dedicated admin connection]
  [-X[1] disable commands, startup script, enviroment variables [and exit]]
  [-x disable variable substitution]
  [-? show syntax summary]
```